# Laravel: How to authenticate users without DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

As the title suggests, is it possible to authenticate without DB (instead, using User Provider)?

I've seen posts about *how to authenticate without password*, but would it be ever possible to authenticate without *DB*?

Here is what I've been trying to achieve...

1. Ask the user to submit a PIN
2. Compare the PIN with a value within .env
3. If the PIN is correct, authenticate the user

It seems to be possible to do authenticate without a traditional RDBMS by [introducing a user provider.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

However, the doc doesn't seem to describe how the user provider should look like.

Here are snippets of my code (well, I simply mimicked the doc)...

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('myUser', function ($app, array $config) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...

            return new MyUserProvider($app->make('myUser'));
        });
    }
}
```

In `auth.php`...

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'myUser',
    ],
],
```

Now, I have no clue as to how to proceed.

So, I'd like to know...

1. How the `user provider` should look like
2. if it's possible to authenticate users with `env()` in the first place

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't looked into it too much, so can't really answer the question very well, but I think you'll want to look at authentication guards in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: @PhilCross Thanks for your comment. Yeah I noticed it too, but doc doesn't explain how to achieve it really well :(

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-guard-in-laravel--cms-29667
https://mattstauffer.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2/
https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/laravel-api-authenticate-user-with-custom-driver-different-table-using-auth-middleware-fa2cabec2d61
Hopefully these might help a little. I haven't read them, but they look alright.

Comment: I think you have to follow this path http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver Not sure exactly. I also do not have any experience in this kind of a situation. Since this is an interesting question I'm also trying to implement this as a learning project.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thank you all, but there was a much simpler solution... which is to use `session()`.

In the controller,

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('pin') === env('PIN')) {
        $request->session()->put('authenticated', time());
        return redirect()->intended('success');
    }

    return view('auth.login', [
        'message' => 'Provided PIN is invalid. ',
    ]);
    //Or, you can throw an exception here.
}
```

The route looks like,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'custom_auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/success', 'Controller@success')->name('success');
});
```

The `custom_auth` will looke like,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!empty(session('authenticated'))) {
        $request->session()->put('authenticated', time());
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: what is the location of the `custom_auth` and did you create a simple `<form>` with just one input where users enter the PIN?

Comment: Please consider not using `env()` into your controller or model. You should create new config file in `config/` directory. If you're using `env()`, you will get `null` value after caching your config. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration)

Comment: Every user has the same pin? Or there is only one User? BC there will only be one pin to the ```env``` variable set to PIN. Am I missing something? There's no way that this works....

Answer (score 28):

Create your own `Guard` ignoring `UserProvider` interface. I adopted it in my project and it's working well.

#### `PinGuard.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Auth\Guards;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class PinGuard
 */
class PinGuard implements Guard
{
    /**
     * @var null|Authenticatable|User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * OpenAPIGuard constructor.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether user is logged in.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check(): bool
    {
        return (bool)$this->user();
    }

    /**
     * Check whether user is not logged in.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function guest(): bool
    {
        return !$this->check();
    }

    /**
     * Return user id or null.
     *
     * @return null|int
     */
    public function id(): ?int
    {
        $user = $this->user();
        return $user->id ?? null;
    }

    /**
     * Manually set user as logged in.
     * 
     * @param  null|\App\User|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUser(?Authenticatable $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(array $credentials = []): bool
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unexpected method call');
    }

    /**
     * Return user or throw AuthenticationException.
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     * @return \App\User
     */
    public function authenticate(): User
    {
        $user = $this->user();
        if ($user instanceof User) {
            return $user;
        }
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }

    /**
     * Return cached user or newly authenticate user.
     *
     * @return null|\App\User|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
     */
    public function user(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user ?: $this->signInWithPin();
    }

    /**
     * Sign in using requested PIN.
     *
     * @return null|User
     */
    protected function signInWithPin(): ?User
    {
        // Implement your logic here
        // Return User on success, or return null on failure
    }

    /**
     * Logout user.
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        if ($this->user) {
            $this->setUser(null);
        }
    }
}
```

#### `NoRememberTokenAuthenticatable.php`

`User` should mixin this trait.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Trait NoRememberTokenAuthenticatable
 *
 * @mixin Model
 */
trait NoRememberTokenAuthenticatable
{
    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unexpected method call');
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unexpected method call');
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unexpected method call');
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unexpected method call');
    }
}
```

#### `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\Guards\PinGuard;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::extend('pin', function (Container $app) {
            return new PinGuard($app['request']);
        });
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

#### `config/auth.php`

You should comment out most of them.

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        // 'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'pin',
        ],
        // 'api' => [
        //     'driver' => 'session',
        //     'provider' => 'users',
        // ],
        // 'web' => [
        //     'driver' => 'session',
        //     'provider' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
        //     'model' => App\User::class,
        // ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    // 'passwords' => [
    //     'users' => [
    //         'provider' => 'users',
    //         'table' => 'password_resets',
    //         'expire' => 60,
    //     ],
    // ],

];
```

Comment: Then you can normally use `Auth` Facade, like `Auth::user()` `Auth::id()`

Comment: should be the aceptes Answer

Comment: I've published the part of this as a library: [mpyw/null-auth: Null Guard for Laravel. Designed for Middleware-based authentication and testing.](https://github.com/mpyw/null-auth)

Comment: Using this solution, how would a normal login without db look like? Please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298133/eloquent-queries-without-database-data-is-retrieved-from-external-api

Comment: And could you please show a code example of how to use this new guard.
I am using this as a login request. But still not passing the auth middleware:
      $user = new User([
                'id'       => $result->success->user->id,
                'name'     => $result->success->user->name,
                'email'    => $result->success->user->email,
                'password' => $password
            ]);
            Auth::setUser($user);
            $re = Auth::authenticate();

Comment: This is fantastic, this is the correct answer, nice work.

Answer (score -5):

If you know who the user is (IE: have a $user instance already), you can simply login without using any guards as shown in the documentation

```
Auth::login($user);
```

I would pass in a User instance instead of $email/$password to your function

```
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
$class->login($user);
```

and then in your class

```
public static function Login(User $user) 
{
// ...
 if(substr ( $result, 0, 3 ) == '+OK')
    Auth::login($user);
    return true; //user will be logged in and then redirect
 else
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion... but I'm in a situation where DB is not available. So, `User::whereEmail` won't get any instance. Also, I don't think that `Auth::login($user)` can be used, since I don't have any user instance.

Comment: Maybe this answer is not the best for the question, but google brought me here and its what I was looking for :)

Comment: Answers provide bits and pieces of information. Would be great if there was a working sample ..  Are there any available?