# How to authenticate user from the respons of rest API in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am creating a laravel application using two laravel applications. The first laravel application will be used for handling API requests, the second one will be used for making a request to the first laravel application. The second application will also have a login form. On the submit of the login form, I am sending the form data to the first application which in return gives back the user data. Now what I want is to log the user into the second application without using its own database(second application database).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602198/laravel-how-to-authenticate-users-without-db check this out

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT for authentication purposes.
In both MS you must use the same Signing Key

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/