# Laravel 8 - Auth::login() do not save $user data on session

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

My stack:

- Laravel 8
- PHP 7.4
- DoctrineORM
- LDAP Auth

I'm trying to do a manual authentication on Laravel (Laravel 8).

But, when I try to save a `$user` variable in Auth, it is not saved.

Login Controller:

```
public function auth(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $auth = Adldap::auth()->attempt($request->user.env('LDAP_USER_SUFIX'), $request->password, true);
        if($auth){
            $userData = Ldap::ldapUserAttributes($request->user);
            $user = new User($userData['name'], $userData['mail']);
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Usuário e/ou senha incorretos');
    }
```

The User class implements the Authenticatable, but it isn't a database entity.

These are my routes (`web.php`):

```
Route::get ('/login',                               [Login::class, 'index'])                                        ->name('login');
Route::post('/login',                               [Login::class, 'auth'])                                         ->name('auth');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [Dashboard::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

If I remove the authentication middleware and print what it receives, NULL is printed.

But, if I print Auth content right after `Auth::login($user);` at Login Controller, the User data is printed on screen.

This is my User implementation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements Authenticatable
{
    private $cpf;
    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $senha;
    private $remember_token;

    public function __construct(string $cpf, string $username, string $email)
    {
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getCpf()
    {
        return $this->cpf;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->cpf;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
}
```

PS.: `Session::set('test', 'test');` and `Session::get('test')` work for me in diferents routes.

`$middlewareGroups` in the Kernel.php

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

My Session is set to save in file

Comment: are these routes in `web.php`?

Comment: Yes, theses routes are in ```web.php```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do an authentication without any type of database query.

The way I was doing it would not work, because at some point there was still an attempt to go to the database to get the user with that specific identifier.

So, I set out to implement my own Guard, which solved my problem.

For that, I followed this example: [Laravel: How to authenticate users without DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602198/laravel-how-to-authenticate-users-without-db), but I adapted to my need